# How to save Object Array as HashMap?

Tags: android, arrays, list, hashmap

I have an object as,

```
{
    "code": 0,
    "data": [
        {
            "id": 71,
            "product_id": 1
        },
        {
            "id": 72,
            "product_id": 3
        }
    ]
}
```

I want to save this `data` Array as Hashmap. How I can convert this easily without using a loop.

Now I am doing like,

```
        HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
        for(Data data: dataArray){
            map.put("id", String.valueOf(data.getId()));
            map.put("product_id",String.valueOf(data.getName()));
        }
```

Comment: what you tried so far?

Comment: Please show us some effort. This is way too common to be searched on Google.

Comment: I updated my Question with the method How I convert the data as HashMap

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a class like this

```
public class Data {
    int id,product_id;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public int getProduct_id() {
        return product_id;
    }

    public void setProduct_id(int product_id) {
        this.product_id = product_id;
    }
}
```

This is mapped to your data json Array.
and then create and add to hashmap like this

```
Data data = new Data();
data.setId(1);
data.setProduct_id(123);
List<Data> dataList = new ArrayList<>();
dataList.add(data);
HashMap<String,List<Data>> hashMap = new HashMap<>();
hashMap.put("<this-should-be-your-key>",dataList);
```